# tunnel server offline: Request failed with status code 502, retry 1s when i run gulp serve

Tags: angularjs, server, gulp

[image]

when i run gulp serve  in angularjs project 
error showing 
tunnel server offline: Request failed with status code 502, retry 1s

Comment: you have to provide sufficient details for asking help kindly go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have angularjs project with gulpfile .. when i run with gulp serve command showing error you can see in image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please make some change in you configuration file

[image] set tunnel=false
until localtunnel.me work correctly